# How is alarm snooze/stop activity loaded in Android 10 if we cannot load activity from BroadcastReceiver in Android 10

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-alarms, android-10.0, keyguard

In Android 10 there was no provision to launch an activity from a background service like BroadcastReceiver. I am curious to understand how android's default alarm application is loading a snooze/stop activity from the background service. I am trying to implement the same functionality but cannot succeed to launch an activity when the BroadcastReceiver is triggered.

**I would like to know how the alarm snooze/stop activity is triggered in the background even though the screen is locked in Android 10**. Thanks in advance for helping me understand the concept behind it

Comment: Android does not have a "default alarm application". Android devices might have one supplied and configured by the device manufacturer. Since device manufacturers control their device and firmware, manufacturer-installed apps often have capabilities that exceed what a third-party developer can achieve. You are also making assumptions about the nature of what that app is doing, such as its use of a background service.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry for the misunderstanding about background services in alarm clock. Is it possible to know what is the architecture they use for alarm?

Comment: Alarm clocks typically use `AlarmManager` and [its `setAlarmClock()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager?hl=en#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), AFAIK.